# Flutter Build failed with an exception in Gradle

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Since a couple of days, my code is no longer working but I don't know what I have changed and no solution on the internet worked for me so far.
Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to fill in the whole issue log because of spam but in the end it says:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

You can also find my whole code here: https://github.com/Burekmasta/BlogApp

[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdGG4.png)

Comment: run following cmd. ```flutter run -v``` and give error log

Comment: Is there any possibility to post it on another way or to contact you private? Because the error log is too long and can't be posted here...